# Editable TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need a treeview with the following features:

1. ability to drag and drop nodes inside the treeview
2. there are buttons on the top, that allow to move items up and down.
3. editable node text

Is there any implementation of this available?
If not all, Is there an implementation of feature 1 available?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The normal treeview can be forced to support this.

Drag n drop nodes:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TreeViewDragDrop.aspx

You can edit labes by setting the "LabelEdit" property to true and then invoke the .BeginEdit() method of a specific tree node.

```
treeView.LabelEdit = true;
treeView.Nodes[0].BeginEdit(); //activates editing of node 0
```

When LabelEdit is enabled, you can also edit node texts by clicking the node text.